# no sound on built-in B&O speakers on HP Pavilion All-in-One Desktop 32-b0xxx with GNU/Linux

Tags: sound, realtek, speakers, hp-pavilion

Dear Ubuntu Community,

The all-in-one HP Pavilion 32" desktop computer (32-b0010ns) has buit-in B&O (Bang & Olufsen) speakers, which work perfectly fine on Windows, but not on any freshly installed GNU/Linux distribution that I know of. I've spent many days trying to solve this issue, tirelessly searching and trying any possible fix, to no avail.

I've tried Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, 22.10, 23.04, 23.10, Linux Mint 21.2 Edge, Fedora... I've also tried pavucontrol, blacklisting snd_hda_codec_realtek, setting different GPIOs or hdajackretasking without really knowing but I was doing.

On a 23.10 fresh install (6.5.0-14-generic Kernel), I have Audio Intel Alder Lake-S HD Audio HP snd_hda_intel with ALC274 Analog. All sound configuration seems ok, microphone works, headphones work, sound bars even move when playing audio, but built-in speakers don't sound, and they are not muted (checked with alsamixer).

What can I do? Is there any terminal output that I can show in order to help solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance for any help.